# image doesn't work in next js. gives error 'hostname'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

when working with next js Image, it picks up an error

next.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ['localhost'],
  },
};
```

error img: [image]

I don't really understand how to set up img and what next js wants from me

image component code:

```
        <Image         
        alt={element.show_name_eng}
        src={'\\' + element.show_picture_1980} - throws an error if not - //

but it works without problems if you use picture + source
        width={200}
        height={100}/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add base URL of image in this code

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ['localhost','https://example.cm'],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [next/image documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#src), if you want to pull images from an external URL, you have to add the image URL domain to your array of allowed domains in the `next.config.js` file.

For instance, if your image `src` is `https://res.cloudinary.com/user/image/upload/v111/memes/dog.jpg`

Then your `next.config.js` file should look like this:

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ['localhost','res.cloudinary.com'],
  },
};
```